# Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS keeps breaking entire ethernet LAN

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, ethernet, crash

[ifconfig](http://pastebin.com/7Sf2nHaP)

[syslog at time of failure](http://pastebin.com/WceNTuhC)

Basically what happens is:

1) I reboot the machine (either with hard shut down or by hitting the reset button)

2) Everything is fine

3) At some random time (within 1-3 days of rebooting), ethernet breaks not just on the server but on every single ethernet device on the network.

Note: Devices on wifi are completely unaffected.

4) Once this issue occurs, system is completely unresponsive. Although I normally only access via ssh and the machine is typically headless, I did temporarily attach a keyboard and monitor for troubleshooting purposes. They are unresponsive after ethernet breaks, so I can't get into the system at all to see what's going on.

I am an extremely novice linux user, so I'm probably missing something really basic here. It was fine until I ran apt-get update a few weeks (maybe months? time is blending in together) ago, then this started happening. It wouldn't be so bad if it wasn't for the fact that all the hard restarts have borked an hdd (i had backups, so more annoying than anything else.. but still), the server crashing also breaks ethernet for everything else in the house (including hubby's PC), and I can't really use it as a reliable fileserver b/c if I leave it doing a file copy overnight, I never know if the copy will be able to complete before the next crash.

The purpose of the machine, as I said, is just a fileserver. All it really does on any given day is run deluge, sshd, and samba to share a couple drives. That's it. This is not a workhorse machine, it's an old PC turned media server.. and it's met my needs fine.. until now. I'm willing to buy a new ethernet card if necessary, but since the whole machine dies and we haven't even really isolated it to the ethernet card yet, I feel that would be premature.

I also have wireshark logs from an affected machine on ethernet that I can peruse if anybody knows something specific to look for. I couldn't see anything jumping out at me (either a lack of traffic or a sudden surge in traffic or weird error messages) that would explain why nothing could connect to ethernet anymore..

It seems to MOST frequently crash at night between 1 and 4 in the morning, but it has also done it during broad daylight, which was disappointing because I thought I had isolated it to cron for a few days. :(

I would love to upgrade to the latest LTS release, but as it is right now, I fear the machine would crash in the middle of it and I'd lose everything and have to start over. Media is all on separate physical drives from the OS, and I could configure samba on a fresh install easily enough... but I could never in a million years remember how I finally got deluge to play nice with my network attached storage device (which I only ever bought one of b/c of how much of a pain it is, the rest of my storage is internal hdds on the server).

EDIT 01/15/2015: System has been upgraded to 14.04.1 LTS. Issue did NOT occur on the 14.04.1 LTS LiveCD, so confirmed NOT hardware. If it continues to occur, then we've isolated to something in my configuration.

Haven't had any system and/or LAN crashes yet (since completing the upgrade), but I've been seeing this in my syslog

```
Jan 15 17:36:36 Atlantis kernel: [ 2740.669050] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link up
Jan 15 17:37:05 Atlantis kernel: [ 2769.664587] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link down
Jan 15 17:37:12 Atlantis kernel: [ 2776.773787] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link up
Jan 15 17:37:15 Atlantis kernel: [ 2779.450847] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link down
Jan 15 17:37:22 Atlantis kernel: [ 2786.557424] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link up
Jan 15 17:39:03 Atlantis kernel: [ 2888.205886] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link down
Jan 15 17:39:11 Atlantis kernel: [ 2895.403580] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link up
Jan 15 17:39:19 Atlantis kernel: [ 2903.777765] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link down
Jan 15 17:39:26 Atlantis kernel: [ 2910.914822] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: eth0: link up
```

So maybe the problem /was/ hardware, but 14.04 manages to keep it from crashing everything?? Gonna leave it up another couple days and see what happens.

EDIT 1/17/15: Happened again. Tried pinging 8.8.8.8 from another machine on the ethernet LAN, first the pings timed out for about a minute, then they started returning "No route to host." Rebooting the server OR just pulling its ethernet cable results in getting the wired LAN back for all machines instantly.

Comment: Do you mean by "breaking entire ethernet LAN" that other machines are affected too? Can you ping 8.8.8.8 on another machine? What do you use as router/switch?

Comment: Yes, ethernet LAN stops working altogether, nobody can ping each other, nobody can access each others' shares, nobody can access the internet, it's as if they weren't connected at all.

The router/modem is a TG1672 from Time Warner.. I used to use a Linksys (with the modem in bridge mode) but it died a while back and I haven't had a chance to get a new one yet.. so I've been using the TWC supplied router.

The server is up at the moment. Next time it crashes I can try to ping outside, although based on prior experience I suspect it'll time out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be hardware problem - network card might be shortening some circuits after it gets warm or tries to go to sleep and causing LAN and PC die. Though not sure 100%.

So if it is possible try to replace network card. If it is integrated then plug in new card and don't use integrated one - don't plug in network cable in old one and disable it from BIOS.

Comment: To test the hardware theory, at the time of the OP, I started downloading a LiveCD to see if I can boot from that and how it'll go. If it still crashes on the LiveCD, then I'll have confirmed hardware. If it doesn't, then well .. still lost.

I don't have a spare ethernet card at the moment (been a wifi household for quite a while at this point), but I can easily pick one up when/if needed this weekend.

Comment: It DOES NOT happen if booted to 14.04 Desktop LiveCD (since apparently there's no server LiveCD anymore..), so we have confirmed not hardware.

Within 4 hours of booting back to normal, it crashed again. Sadly this was in the middle of attempting to upgrade to 14.04 so the system is now even more borked than it was. I'm tempted to reinstall, but I really want to know what specifically is causing this problem, because I know one of the major mistakes many novices make is reinstalling because they can't figure something out.

Comment: Managed to salvage the borked install (yay linux), so now I have a working server again .. aside from the random crashes, of course.